# How i can set the increasing of enumerate, that depends on condition?

Tags: python, enumerate

I have got the following loop^

```
i = 0
for var in vars:
    if var[ "ID" ] != 0 and var[ "ID" ] & 1:
        print i, var[ "ID" ]
        i += 1
```

Can I use `enumerate` for this loop instead of counter `i` ? How i can set the increasing of enumerate,  that depends on this condition: `if var[ "ID" ] != 0 and var[ "ID" ] & 1:`

Comment: `x['ID'] != 0 and x['ID'] & 1` - isn't just the second part of this condition sufficient?

Comment: @eurmiro: Yes, it is sufficient in the current context (an `if` etc statement). Otherwise there is a subtle difference when the variable == 0; in that case the whole evaluates to False, but the second part evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `filter`:

```
>>> vs = [{'ID': 1}, {'ID': 4}]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x['ID'] & 1, vs)):
...     print i, v
...
0 {'ID': 1}
```

Comment: @G-71 hard to say. you should probably test this if performance is critical here.

Comment: @G-71 - it is compacter and the value of `i` is correct in any moment. Anyway, I think `print` is here the slowest part.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can use `enumerate` to simplify this code (not without thinning `vars` first, so that `enumerate` would only apply to elements that match the condition).

To be honest, I think the code is pretty straightforward as it is.